# android-emulator exiting with code 2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-x86

my android-emulator kept saying that haxm was unable to open the vm and then exiting with code 2.
Haxm was installed on the system with android properly, my bios supports V-Tx and it is enabled and it was properly installed via the android SDK manager. I spent 15 hours pulling my hair out installing different SDK's, and images, and versions of android-studio including the newest canary. Nothing worked. Haxm was installed properly.

Answer (score 0):

I am now answering my own question because there isnt anything posted on the internet with the solution. 
I finally found that I needed to enable in Windows Features:
`Windows HyperVisor Platform`and`Virtual Machine Platform.`
 This is the fix that was required and everything worked fine.